# Keyboard dismisses on every character typed in text input in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have one textField.

```
private var verseTitle: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "TITLE"
    tf.font = UIFont(suite16: .tBlackItalic, size: 18)
    tf.textColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    tf.returnKeyType = .done
    tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tf
}()
```

In viewDidLoad method, I have assigned self as delegate.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    verseTitle.delegate = self
}
```

In viewDidLayout method, I'm using stack view to add textField to the view.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    //Title
    let titleStack = UIStackView()
    titleStack.axis = .horizontal
    titleStack.alignment = .center
    titleStack.distribution = .equalSpacing
    titleStack.spacing = 8
    
    titleStack.addArrangedSubview(verseTitle)
    titleStack.addArrangedSubview(floorView)
    titleStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(titleStack)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        floorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 13),
        floorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 13),
        
        
        titleStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        titleStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
])
}
```

Now, the problem I'm facing is, that when I start typing in the textField, the keyboard gets dismissed only after I type one letter. I'm not sure why this is happening. I have to tap on the field after entering each letter. For some reason, the focus is taken away from the field after each letter is entered (unless I tap on a suggested autocorrect - the whole string is correctly added to the string at once)

Comment: pls edit the post and add all the relevant code to your problemo

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ..what about your delegate methods?

Comment: Does it happen when you run your app on a device rather than on a simulator? Starting from Xcode 13, simulator's keyboard always gets dismissed when you start typing on your Mac's keyboard.

Comment: @Vadim Belyaev Do you have a solution for this? The new default behaviour drives me crazy...

Comment: @Cydie, I wasn't able to find a solution. I didn't like this change either but seems like it's something we'll have to live with. As a workaround I just type by clicking on the on-screen keyboard when I really need to test text input with the keyboard being visible.

Comment: @AndreiG.
I've not defined delegate methods yet.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev
this issue continues on the physical device too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's going on here is your view, including the `UITextField` gets re-created after each keystroke because your view construction is in: 
[`viewDidLayoutSubviews()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews), `When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this method.`

To fix it, move the code to `ViewDidLoad`, so the view is created only once:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    verseTitle.delegate = self
    
    let titleStack = UIStackView()
    titleStack.axis = .horizontal
    titleStack.alignment = .center
    titleStack.distribution = .equalSpacing
    titleStack.spacing = 8
    
    titleStack.addArrangedSubview(verseTitle)
    titleStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(titleStack)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        titleStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        titleStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
    ])
}
```